# jQuery window.on resize not firing at the right time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

```
$myWindow.on('resize', function(){
var $width = $myWindow.width();
if ($width > 870) {
  console.log('hey im 870');
  $('#the-team-wrapper .flex-content').empty();
  ajax_results.done(function(data) {
          // console.log(data.job_titles[3]);

          var employee_job_titles;


          function job_titles_display(jobtitle,ind){
            if (jobtitle.job_titles[ind].length>1) {
              var my_array = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < jobtitle.job_titles[ind].length; i++){
                my_array.push(jobtitle.job_titles[ind][i][0]['title']);
                employee_job_titles = my_array.join(' | ');
              }
            }else {
              var employee_job_titles;
              employee_job_titles = jobtitle.job_titles[ind][0]['title'];
            }
            return employee_job_titles;
          }


          for (var i = 0; i < data.employee_info.length; i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0){
              $('#the-team-wrapper .flex-content').append('<div class="profile-parent"><div class="employee-profile-pic flex-item" data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'"></div><div class="employee-bio-wrapper flex-item"><h2 data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'">'+data.employee_info[i]['firstname']+" "+data.employee_info[i]['lastname']+'</h2><h3 data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'">'+job_titles_display(data,i)+
              '</h3><p class="employee-bio-text employee-bio-text-not-active">'+data.employee_info[i]['bio']+'</p></div><button type="button" class="bio-prev-butt-left">View '+data.employee_info[i]['firstname']+'\'s'+' Bio</button><div class="hide-bio-close-button-left">x</div></div>');
            }else {
              $('#the-team-wrapper .flex-content').append('<div class="profile-parent"><div class="employee-bio-wrapper flex-item"><h2 data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'">'+data.employee_info[i]['firstname']+" "+data.employee_info[i]['lastname']+'</h2><h3 data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'">'+job_titles_display(data,i)+'</h3 data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+
              '"><p class="employee-bio-text employee-bio-text-not-active">'+data.employee_info[i]['bio']+'</p></div><div class="employee-profile-pic flex-item" data-id="'+data.employee_info[i]['id']+'"></div><button type="button" class="bio-prev-butt-right">View '+data.employee_info[i]['firstname']+'\'s'+' Bio</button><div class="hide-bio-close-button-right">x</div></div>');
            }

            var profile_pic_path = data.employee_info[i]['profile_pic'].split('\\').join('\\\\');
            $("#the-team-wrapper .flex-content-wrapper .flex-content .employee-profile-pic:eq("+i+")").css({'background': 'url(_employee_pics/'+profile_pic_path+')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-position': 'center', 'background-size': 'cover'});
          }

        });

}
```

I have this code, and it should fire when width is greater than 870, but instead it fires when width is greater than 970 on Opera, and when width is about 890 on Chrome. How can I fix this and get consistent results across browsers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: adding + 'px' doesn't work because .width() just returns a numeric value when I console log it there is no suffix with px or anything.

Comment: I tested this `$(window).on('resize', function(){
if ($(window).width() > 870.00) {
  console.log("current width: "+ $(window).width())
 }
});` on this page via Opera's JS console and it worked fine after window width 870px. Opera version: 40.0.2308.81; SO is using JQuery 1.12.4; Could it be a version issue?

Comment: Also no issue with Chrome 53.0.2785.143 as far as I can see.

Comment: @ŽaMan not sure whats up with my set tried other version of jquery still same problems even on edge it fires at a different time.

Comment: Taile and you're sure it's not the issue of "swinging" the mouse fast side-to-side like @Robusto answered? It's true I can make the function execute at different window widths by quickly resizing the window. The jumps went like so `current width: 908 / current width: 1016`

Comment: @ŽaMan i've updated the code in my question to exactly what i'm doing on the resize

Comment: meant to tag you with @ but there seems to be an issue for me to do that

Comment: Just guessing as I don't know how much data you're collecting using ajax but could the problem be more with the ajax load time than window resize?

Comment: @ŽaMan doesnt seem to be ajax tried it with a simple log statement only and same crazy results and the result is consistent in browser of by about 100 in opera and off by about 20 in chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125190/discussion-between-zaman-and-patrick-traile).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS reset to neutralize the browser's default `margin` or `padding` on the `<body>` element?

Different browsers add different amounts of either `padding` or `margin` to the `<body>` of the page, which could explain why the function is triggered at different points in different browsers.

Comment: The `body` default padding or margin would never be 20px, much less 100px.

Comment: @danwellman I have resets on html and body tags setting padding margin and borders to 0 but same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the `resize` event fires at different times and rates depending on browser, CPU load, and how fast you actually do the resizing.

Test the following code in your browsers. When I do this in a clean browser at a reasonable rate of coverage the difference usually comes in within around 2px of the target.

(BTW, you'll see I am caching the jQuery selectors into variables. Not strictly necessary for this test, but you might be surprised to find out how many bugs I've fixed because coders have invoked uncached jQuery selectors willy-nilly in loops and other repetitive places throughout their code).

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.on('resize',function(){
  var w = $window.width();
  if (w > 1000) {
    console.log( w );
  } else {
    console.log('nope: ' + w)
  }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question to show exactly what i'm doing on the resize I tried your answer but still no luck for me